# C# Capturing Screenshot with zoom enabled in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, zooming, screenshot, imaging

I've just started writing this small C# program, purpose irrelevant. For now it tries to make a screenshot of the whole screen and it succeeds... kind of...

The catch is that I am running Windows with 200% zoom (no, I don't have poor eyesight) and when I run this code I get only 1/4 of the screen saved (upper left part), not the whole as intended. I am more than sure that this is to do with the 200% zoom and I am asking if anyone can suggest a workaround so it actually captures my whole screen. Here's the code:

```
        string savePath = @"C:\Users\eltaro\Desktop\ScreenShot "+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+" at "+DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm")+".bmp";
        bmpImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage);
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        bmpImage.Save(savePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: You should verify if `CopyFromScreen` still leaks handles. If you keep capturing screenshots, and it does, you'll eventually run out of handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this problem ended up being solved by my friend, but since he does not dwell here, I will write the answer myself.

The solvent was actually in app.manifest, this one line solves the problem entirely:

< dpiAware >true< /dpiAware >

Comment: I have the same issue . I am doing work in WPF Desktop Application

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN : Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Size): Performs a bit-block transfer of the color data, corresponding to a rectangle of pixels, from the screen to the drawing surface of the Graphics."

You have to define this yourself when you working with zoomed screen, or multiple monitors. `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width`, because this constant defines the size of the screen/resolution of the screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the result of my code, unedited:

http://puu.sh/4piTs.bmp

And this is the result if I switch the Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width & Height to 2880 and 1800:

http://puu.sh/4piVl.bmp

Comment: so, in other words, if you don't view the images, if I change the values to 2880 for width and 1800 for height, the screenshot becomes the full size, but still takes only the upper left part and fills the rest with black.

Comment: you have set the same in CopyFromScreen() Method also. did you change the parameters?

Comment: ^Have not done that before you mentioned it. I have tried it now and now the whole screenshot is black O_o

Comment: please look at the link,http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41b45655-7925-469c-99ba-b5c6b206fd52/take-a-screenshot-of-the-entire-screen-with-dual-monitor-support

Answer (score 0):

Set the

```
Screen.WorkingArea
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Height, Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Width, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx

and get a screeen shot

Comment: I am sorry to say this yields no change to the captured screenshot. It still takes only the upper left 1/4 of the screen.

Also, you mixed up the placement of height and width. They are the other way around.